# In Coq, which tactic to change the goal from `S x = S y` to `x = y`

Tags: proof, coq

I want to change the goal from `S x = S y` to `x = y`. It's like `inversion`, but for the goal instead of a hypothesis.

Such a tactic seems legit, because when we have `x = y`, we can simply use `rewrite` and `reflexivity` to prove the goal.

Currently I always find myself using `assert (x = y)` to introduce a new subgoal, but it's tedious to write when `x` and `y` are complex expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tactic **`apply f_equal.`** will do what you want, for any constructor or function.

The lema `f_equal` shows that for any function `f`, you always have `x = y -> f x = f y`.  This allows you to reduce the goal from `f x = f y` to `x = y`:

```
Proposition myprop (x y: nat) (H : x = y) : S x = S y.
Proof.
  apply f_equal.  assumption.
Qed.
```

(The `injection` tactic implements the converse implication — that for some functions, and in particular for constructors, `f x = f y -> x = y`.)

Comment: You can also use the `f_equal` tactic, which saves some typing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the `injection` tactic: http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#@tactic126

Comment: This is not correct: “injection” implements implications of the form `f x = f y -> x = y` (and this does not hold for arbitrary functions `f`, only for special cases for constructors); what OP describes is just using the converse implication `x = y -> f x = f y`, which holds for any function.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread the question and thought that the issue was when `S x = S y` occurs in hypothesis.