# Coq: remove constructor from both sides of goal

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Consider the following partial proof:

```
Theorem test : forall (n m : nat),
  n = m -> S n = S m.
Proof.
  intros n m H.
```

Executing until this point gives me the following:

```
1 subgoal
n, m : nat
H : n = m
______________________________________(1/1)
S n = S m
```

I would like to remove the `S`s from the goal, obtaining the goal `n = m`. Is there a tactic that does this?

Comment: The current question seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37490891/2747511) question and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13749403/2747511).

Comment: Eventually you might find it interesting to note that this essentially is just a `match` statement, but an advanced form that uses a `return` annotation to let Coq's type system "cast" the type `S n = S n` to `S n = S m` .  Try `apply (match H in (_ = n2) return (S _ = S n2) with eq_refl => eq_refl end).`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `f_equal` tactic.

Comment: what if we want to remove the constructor in both sides of the hypothesis ?

Comment: That would be `injection` you are looking for